# Serialize abstract class with custom node name for each concrete class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an array of Fruit objects, some of them Oranges, some of them Apples.
I would like to serialize them to a list that looks like:

```
<Fruits>
    <AppleFruit>
         <IsRotten>true</IsRotten>
         <FellFarFromTree>false</FellFarFromTree>
    </AppleFruit>
    <OrangeFruit>
         <IsRotten>false</IsRotten>
         <NumberOfSegments>6</NumberOfSegments>
    </OrangeFruit>
</Fruits>
```

So I'm trying the following:

```
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Apple))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Orange))]
public abstract class Fruit {
    public bool IsRotten { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("AppleFruit")]
public class Apple : Fruit {
    public bool FellFarFromTree { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot("OrangeFruit")]
public class Orange : Fruit {
    public int NumberOfSegments { get; set; }
}

public class Blender {
    public void XmlBlend(params Fruit[] fruits) {
        using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\test\blended_fruits.xml", Encoding.UTF8)) {
            writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            writer.WriteStartDocument();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Fruits");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Fruit));

            foreach (var fruit in fruits) {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, fruit);
            }

            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteEndDocument();
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void TestIt () {
        var blender = new Blender();
        blender.XmlBlend(
            new Apple() {
                FellFarFromTree = false,
                IsRotten = true
            },
            new Orange() {
                IsRotten = false,
                NumberOfSegments = 6
            });
    }
}
```

But the XmlRoot attribute seems to be totally ignored.   The actual output comes out looking like:

```
<Fruits>
  <Fruit xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Apple">
    <IsRotten>true</IsRotten>
    <FellFarFromTree>false</FellFarFromTree>
  </Fruit>
  <Fruit xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Orange">
    <IsRotten>false</IsRotten>
    <NumberOfSegments>6</NumberOfSegments>
  </Fruit>
</Fruits>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlRoot() for Xml Serilization does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440845/xmlroot-for-xml-serilization-does-not-work)  (Try `XmlType()`)

Comment: `XmlType("AppleFruit")` just changes the `xsi:type` to `"AppleFruit"`

Comment: Close, but no cigar.  That yields 
  <Fruit xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="AppleFruit">  (note that the xsi:type attribute has changed, but not the node name)

Comment: @MikeRuhlin - Do any of the other suggestions from that answer (`XmlElement()`, using `XmlAttributeOverrides`), help?

Comment: Nope.  XmlElement() is for cases where you want to give all the elements in the list the same node name.  XmlAttributeOverrides does same behavior as what I already have.

Answer (score 1):

Answering with my own workaround, but if somebody has a better answer I'll accept it.

I created a different serializer for each class and stuck them in a dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer> ShouldntHaveToDoThis = new Dictionary<Type, XmlSerializer>() {
    {typeof(Apple), new XmlSerializer(typeof(Apple))},
    {typeof(Orange), new XmlSerializer(typeof(Orange))}
};
```

then get the appropriate serializer for each item:

```
        foreach (var fruit in fruits) {
            var serializer = ShouldntHaveToDoThis[fruit.GetType()];
            serializer.Serialize(writer, fruit);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to create a type for `Fruits` with a list of each type of `Fruit` and use the [`XmlElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) attribute to name the items.

```
[XmlRoot("Fruits")]
public class Fruits
{
    [XmlElement("AppleFruit")]
    public Apple[] Apples { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("OrangeFruit")]
    public Orange[] Oranges { get; set; }
}
[Serializable]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Apple))]
[XmlInclude(typeof(Orange))]
public abstract class Fruit {
    public bool IsRotten { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Apple : Fruit {
    public bool FellFarFromTree { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class Orange : Fruit {
    public int NumberOfSegments { get; set; }
}


public void XmlBlend(Fruits fruits) {
    using (var writer = new XmlTextWriter(@"c:\test\blended_fruits.xml", Encoding.UTF8)) {
        writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Fruits));
        serializer.Serialize(writer, fruits);
    }
}
```

Produces output like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fruits xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <AppleFruit>
    <IsRotten>true</IsRotten>
    <FellFarFromTree>false</FellFarFromTree>
  </AppleFruit>
  <OrangeFruit>
    <IsRotten>false</IsRotten>
    <NumberOfSegments>6</NumberOfSegments>
  </OrangeFruit>
</Fruits>
```

Having to list out `Apple[] Apples`, etc. isn't exactly pretty, but I see it as akin to needing `[XmlInclude(typeof(Apple))]` on `Fruit`.