# Xml serialization of objects with array property

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization

In the following composition please note the serialization attributes are lowercase and the array property in the root is serialized accordingly but its child element are not honoring this decoration.

I spected this:

```
<engine>
  <servos>
    <servo>
    </servo>
  </servos>
</engine>
```

But instead i get this:

```
<engine>
  <servos>
    <Servo> <!-- here is the problem-->
    </Servo>
  </servos>
</engine>
```

Code:

```
    [XmlRoot( "engine" )]
    public class Engine {

    [XmlArray( "servos" )]
    public List<Servo> Servos { 
        get { return servos; } 
        set { servos = value; } 
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot( "servo" )] //Child ignoring lowercase decoration 
    public class Servo {
    }
```

What is the correct way to serialize as indicated by the attribute?

Comment: possible duplicate of [XmlRoot() for Xml Serilization does not work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440845/xmlroot-for-xml-serilization-does-not-work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add XmlArrayItem attribute to the `Servos` property:

```
 [XmlArrayItem( "servo" )]
 [XmlArray("servos")]
 public List<Servo> Servos { 
     get;
     set ;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Although the answer pointed by @toATwork works, i prefer this because is more clear the intention of the attribute XmlArrayItem than XmlType for this cases.